# Exception can't create user using ASP.NET Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have encountered a problem when trying to connect an ASP.net web application to SQL Server Enterprise edition after I added the following packages:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.OWIN
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core 
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework
```

When I try to register a user I get this error exception.
I created a test method to test that the connection is working fine and it connected fine to my database server.
The exception:

> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system
>   cannot find the file specified
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 16:             var manager =
>   Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager();
>   Line 17:             var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName =
>   Email.Text, Email = Email.Text }; Line 18:             IdentityResult
>   result = manager.Create(user, Password.Text); Line 19:             if
>   (result.Succeeded) Line 20:             {
>
> Source File: c:\Users\abdallaelnajjar\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\CRMLight\CRMLight\Account\Register.aspx.cs    Line: 18
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file
>   specified]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 40 - Could not
>   open a connection to SQL Server)]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   +5340655    System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +244
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo,
>   SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
>   Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean
>   integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +5350915
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean
>   withFailover) +145
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +922
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer
>   timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +307
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) +518
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +278
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +732
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +85
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1057
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection) +196
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +146
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +16
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +94
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +110    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<Open>b__38(DbConnection
>   t, DbConnectionInterceptionContext c) +10
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget
>   target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext,
>   Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.Open(DbConnection
>   connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +360
>
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass31.<UsingConnection>b__2f()
>   +337    System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +10
>
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1
>   operation) +189
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action
>   operation) +78
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection
>   sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +238
>
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection
>   sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +556
>   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) +250
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) +87
>
> [ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a
>   ProviderManifestToken string.]
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) +271
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices
>   providerServices, DbConnection connection) +33
>
> [ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred accessing the
>   database. This usually means that the connection to the database
>   failed. Check that the connection string is correct and that the
>   appropriate DbContext constructor is being used to specify it or find
>   it in the application's config file. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386386 for information on
>   DbContext and connections. See the inner exception for details of the
>   failure.]
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices
>   providerServices, DbConnection connection) +246
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(Tuple`3
>   k) +32
>
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
>   key, Func`2 valueFactory) +72
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) +251
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection
>   connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest) +56
>
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection
>   providerConnection) +43
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext
>   internalContext) +62
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) +123
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>   +610    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType) +18
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +52
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Include(String path)
>   +18    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.Include(String path) +64
>
>   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include(IQueryable`1 source,
>   String path) +115
>   System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.Include(IQueryable`1 source,
>   Expression`1 path) +154
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.GetUserAggregateAsync(Expression`1
>   filter) +283
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.FindByNameAsync(String
>   userName) +615
>
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManager`2.FindByNameAsync(String
>   userName) +56
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.d__4.MoveNext() +392
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.d__0.MoveNext()
>   +251    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.d__0.MoveNext()
>   +675    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.d__d.MoveNext()
>   +581    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AsyncHelper.RunSync(Func`1
>   func) +159
>
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserManagerExtensions.Create(UserManager`2
>   manager, TUser user, String password) +120
>   CRMLight.Account.Register.CreateUser_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>   in c:\Users\abdallaelnajjar\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\CRMLight\CRMLight\Account\Register.aspx.cs:18
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9615682
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +103
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +35    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1724
>   my connection string

```
  <add name="crmlightEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.CRMLightModel.csdl|res://*/Models.CRMLightModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.CRMLightModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=sqlserver;initial catalog=crmlight;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" /></connectionStrings>
```

just wording when I  install the packages it should be install tables for  ASP.NET Identity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your database connection - your application is not able to connect to database.
It will be in your web.config file in ConnectionSettings.

That is the reason for this error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Maybe the app.config has a good connection string for your unit tests vs the web config which has another connection string.

Comment: hi I add connection string